# What causes re-rendering? and how to avoid it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm having some troubles in a implementation with **React**, **Redux** and **Hooks**.

I do not know how to avoid this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as R from "ramda";

function Main() {
  const mainBanners = useSelector(state => state.mainBanners);
  const features = useSelector(state => state.features);
  const banners = useSelector(state => state.banners);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMainBanners());
    dispatch(fetchFeatures());
    dispatch(fetchBanner());
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log(features);

  return (
    <div className="Main">
      {R.isEmpty(mainBanners || features) ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <MainBanner mainBanners={mainBanners} features={features} />
      )}

      <Banners banners={banners} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

The result `console.log`  of this example  is as follows:

[image: total-console.log]

Comment: What are you trying to avoid? Why rerenders there are bad for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three different `useSelector` calls, and you are executing fetches for three different sets of data.  So yes, I would expect that to result in a total of four separate renders:

1. Initial render
2. Render after `mainBanners` is fetched
3. Render after `features` is fetched
4. Render after `banners` is fetched

This is both expected based on the code you have written, and fine in general, given that your component *might* want to render something different when any of those changes.